# Asignar consulta CTE a una Variable para resultado JSON (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, json, cte

He venido haciendo consultas SQL las cuales necesito formatear como json, por ejemplo de esta manera:

```
select * from tabla for json path;
```

con lo cual cuando la cantidad de datos es mucha el json resultante salia cortado, lo que pude solucionar con lo siguiente:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max);
set @json = (select * from tabla for json path);
select @json;
```

con lo cual obtengo el json completo.
Pero para esta consulta CTE no encuentro la forma de asignarla a una variable:

```
with cte1 (columnaX) as (select * from tabla1 for json path),
cte2 (columnaY) as (select * from tabla2 for json path)
select * from columnaX, columnaY
for json path
```

la CTE funciona, pero cuando son muchos datos vuelve a resultar un json cortado.
Como podria asignar esa consulta a una variable? con el metodo de los primeros ejemplos obtengo error.

Answer (score 1):

Una manera de realizar la asignación, es cumplimentar la salida de la cte en otra.

```
Declare @json nvarchar(max)=N'';

with cte1 (columnaX) as (select * from tabla1 for json path),
     cte2 (columnaY) as (select * from tabla2 for json path),
     cte3 (resultado) as (select * from cte1, cte2
for json path
)
Select @json = resultado from cte3;
```

Comment: ¿el from debiera ser de `cte1, cte2`, no?

Comment: @jachguate Tienes toda la razón. Gracias